# Set vim updatetime for a specific file type

Tags: vim

I would like to modify vim's `updatetime` for files with a specific extension. I've tried accomplishing this by adding the following line to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.t set updatetime=60000
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I open up a file with a `.t` extension and type `:set ut?` I see the default `updatetime=4000`.

Answer (score 10):

The `'updatetime'` setting is a global setting, it is not meant to have different values for different buffers. Why do you want a different value?

You can work around this with autocmds, as you've attempted. However, the `BufRead,BufNewFile` events will only fire when a buffer is loaded; it won't update the setting as you switch buffers. The correct way is to define two autocmds on `BufEnter`; a general one to reset the setting, and (following that, so that it is executed after the first!) one that matches your file patterns and manipulates the setting:

```
autocmd BufEnter * set updatetime=4000
autocmd BufEnter *.t set updatetime=60000
```